# How to learn about the internals of Swing keystroke handling

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, key-bindings, keystroke

Swing can be a frustrating beast.  Especially if you are trying to design an application with it that goes "against the grain" of the assumptions that the Swing designers used in designing Swing.  We have requirements that assign functionality to keystrokes that are way out of the normal.  Yesterday, the issue was that `JComboBox` and `JScrollPane` considered keys like PageUp and PageDown "navigation keys" and grabbed these in spite of our attempts to remap them to other uses when such components had focus.  You might say, that's poor design, but those are our requirements.  There are even special keyboard that have labels indicating these functional remappings and we have to meet those.  Such is life.

Today, another issue has popped up that a `JTextPane` seems to be grabbing the F6 key when it has focus.  When other components have focus, not a problem.  WTF?

And so, my question is simply this:  Is there any documentation on what keystrokes each type of Swing component is grabbing and placing outside the normal `InputMap/ActionMap` system that application level programmers are urged to follow?  I know this depends further on the `LookAndFeel`, and that what happens in `Motif` may be different than what happens in `Metal`, etc.  Still, even drilling down to this level, is this stuff documented anywhere?  I would like to know this so I might know at the start where my problems are going to lie instead of learning this one at a time.  If I know where the problems are I know how to work around them.  But I have source code, java docs, and I just don't know where to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any documentation on what keystrokes each type of Swing component is grabbing and placing outside the normal InputMap/ActionMap system that application level programmers are urged to follow?

No documentation that I'm aware of.

Maybe [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) list will help you out.

Comment: One of my favorite utilities.

Answer (score 1):

The article [*Keypad Panel*](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel) links to related tutorials and shows an example.

Comment: Sorry, this is basic newbie level stuff.  Did you even read my question?